# Print how many time is left for the loop to end in seconds

Tags: c

I'm running a while loop that ends after some seconds.

And I would like to print in seconds, how many time is left for the cycle to end.

My code:

```
time_t end = time(NULL) + seconds;

while (time(NULL) < end) {
     //print time in seconds
}
```

How can I do that? thank you.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", end-time(NULL))`, unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Example: If my seconds variable is equal to 60, I would like to print in the while loop 59, 58, 57...

Comment: Does your loop take exactly one second to complete one cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple calculation such as `end-time(NULL)`. But when you will want to print it in your while loop, you will be seeing many repeated same numbers like this: **(10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,.......)**. To prevent it, you should check in every loop for the repeated number and inhibit it to be printed out again. You can do it like this;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>


int main(void){

int seconds = 10;
int checker = -1;

time_t end = time(NULL) + seconds;

while (time(NULL) < end) {

     if( end-time(NULL) != checker)
     printf("Time Left: %d\n", end-time(NULL));

     checker = end-time(NULL);
}

}
```

Comment: `checker` is undefined.

Comment: Note that you start with checker uninitialized so there is no telling what will happen the first time `if` is called.